# Which one How should I say: This is my most-loved picture or my most loved picture

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct?
most-loved (or) most loved
How should I say: This is my most-loved picture or my most loved picture.

Comment: Even apart from the hyphenation question, this version suggests that you are a painter or filmmaker, and that of all your works this is the one that *your public* loves most. If your meaning is instead that the picture in question is the one that *you* love most, the usual term is *favorite.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation "loved" is an adjective and generally, it's not good to merge "most" and an adjective by a "-".
So, the answer is, "the most loved".

Comment: Hello, M. Rostami. ELU prizes answers that are accompanied by supporting material from a recognised authority, such as CGEL, OED or at a pinch CMoS. Could you possibly add a reference to support your claim, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite picture.

This is my best-selling picture.

This is my most popular picture.

This is the picture I love most.

What are you trying to say exactly?